# Error by 200 Status ok

Tags: angular, typescript

I try to login in my app, i get response 200 but its valid:
Message 200, Status OK, ok : false. What mean ok: false? And how can i deal with that problem? Here is my code to post login in angular:

```
public callLogin(username, password): Observable<HttpResponse<any>> {
const observable = new Subject<HttpResponse<any>>();
const formData: FormData = new FormData();
formData.append('username', username);
formData.append('password', password);
this.http.post('/login', formData, {observe: 'response'})
  .subscribe(res => {
      console.log('hello, I am a result ',res);
      this.currUser= someFactory.fromObject(res.body['some']);
      sessionStorage.setItem(this.CURR_USER, JSON.stringify(this.currUser));

      observable.next(res);
    },
    err => {
      sessionStorage.removeItem(this.currUser);
      this.errorHandler(err);
    }
  );
return observable;
 }
```

and

```
  private errorHandler(error: Error | any): Observable<any> {
  console.error(`Error: ${error.status} ${error.statusText} ${error.name}`);
  return Observable.throw(error);
 }
```

Comment: Is not that a problem with CORS?

Comment: nope ;/ in spring config i use .permitAll().and().csrf().disable().cors()    .disable().httpBasic();